# Identify binary columns

Tags: r

I would like to identify binary columns in a data.frame.

For example, this table

```
my.table <-read.table(text="a,b,c
0,2,0
0.25,1,1
1,0,0", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE,sep = ",")
```

would give `FALSE, FALSE, TRUE`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
apply(my.table,2,function(x) { all(x %in% 0:1) })
```

(or

```
apply(my.table,2,function(x) { all(na.omit(x) %in% 0:1) })
```

if you want to allow for `NA` values)

Comment: I might try to catch binary variables with differnt levels than 0,1 with function(x) length(unique(x))>2. maybe?

Comment: And if they aren't all coded with 0,1 you could check `length(unique(x)` for only two values.

Comment: @Seth, @Joran, those are nice ideas, but if your table were `matrix(c(0,1,0,1,1,2),nrow=3)` would you want the second column being detected as binary??  You'd have to be a little more careful. That is, I guess it depends how you define "binary".

Comment: Maybe `sapply` in place of `apply(.,2)`?!. I heard(read somewhere) that `sapply` might be faster.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to accept binary columns with NA in them, the following should do the trick:

```
is.binary <- function(v) {
  x <- unique(v)
  length(x) - sum(is.na(x)) == 2L
}

my.table <- data.frame(a=11:15, b=c(T,F,T,NA,T), c=c('foo',NA,'bar','bar','foo'))
vapply(my.table, is.binary, logical(1))
#    a     b     c 
#FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

...or if you only accept 0,1,NA:

```
is.binary <- function(v) {
  x <- unique(v)
  length(x) - sum(is.na(x)) == 2L && all(x[1:2] == 0:1)
}
```

Comment: see my comment above -- I think basing 'binary' on `length(unique(x))==2` could be dangerous ...