# How could I make this R snippet faster and more R-ish?

Tags: r, function, performance, lapply

Coming from various other languages, I find R powerful and intuitive, but I am not thrilled with its performance. So I decided to try to improve some snippet I wrote and learn how to code better in R.

Here's a function I wrote, trying to determine if a vector is binary-valued (two distinct values or just one value) or not:

```
isBinaryVector <- function(v) {
  if (length(v) == 0) {
    return (c(0, 1))
  }
  a <- v[1]
  b <- a
  lapply(v, function(x) { if (x != a && x != b) {if (a != b) { return (c()) } else { b = x }}})
  if (a < b) {
    return (c(a, b))
  } else {
    return (c(b, a))
  }
}
```

EDIT: This function is expected to look through a vector then return `c()` if it is not binary-valued, and return `c(a, b)` if it is, a being the small value and b being the larger one (if a == b then just `c(a, a)`. E.g., for

```
  A B C
1 1 1 0
2 2 2 0
3 3 1 0
```

I will `lapply` this `isBinaryVector` and get:

```
$A
[1] 1 1

$B
[1] 1 1

$C
[1] 0 0
```

The time it took on a moderate sized dataset (about 1800 * 3500, 2/3 of them are binary-valued) is about 15 seconds. The set contains only floating-point numbers.

Is there anyway I could do this faster?

Thanks for any inputs!

Comment: I'll be honest, this function makes absolutely no sense to me. Could you provide an example of its use? Is it intended to take a data frame? Is a binary variable one with only 0/1, or one with only two distinct values?

Comment: @joran: Well it might not make much sense:) I just want to separate a data frame into two parts, a set of nominal valued columns and a set of binary valued (or two distinct valued, as you said) columns. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I don't understand how this function could actually work. Your `lapply` call isn't assigned to anything. If v is a data frame, a and b are both initially simply the first column of v. Then you test whether each column is identical to a and b (which themselves are identical) incorrectly using vectorized comparisons in an if statement. I could go on. Consider me baffled.

Comment: Could you provide an example moderate-sized data set?  Also, this is probably better suited to the [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Please add at least two things to your question: 1) Description in words what you are trying to do. 2) Sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are essentially trying to write a function that returns TRUE if a vector has exactly two unique values, and FALSE otherwise.

Try this:

```
> dat <- data.frame(
+   A = 1:3,
+   B = c(1, 2, 1), 
+   C = 0
+ )
> 
> sapply(dat, function(x)length(unique(x))==2)
    A     B     C 
FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Next, you want to get the min and max value. The function `range` does this.  So:

```
> sapply(dat, range)
     A B C
[1,] 1 1 0
[2,] 3 2 0
```

And there you have all the ingredients to make a small function that is easy to understand and should be extremely quick, even on large amounts of data:

```
isBinary <- function(x)length(unique(x))==2

binaryValues <- function(x){
  if(isBinary(x)) range(x) else NA
}

sapply(dat, binaryValues)

$A
[1] NA

$B
[1] 1 2

$C
[1] NA
```

Comment: Both yours and Justin's version use 0.19s on the dataset. Thanks!

Comment: @ZiyaoWei Just shows that performance is often a function of the programmer, not the language!  Good luck with your project.

Comment: I know I am really unexperienced at R:) Perhaps I should buy your upcoming book, but hopefully when it comes out I've passed that stage. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This function returns true or false for vectors (or columns of a data frame):

```
is.binary <- function(v) {
  x <- unique(v)
  length(x) - sum(is.na(x)) == 2L
}
```

Also take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830963/identify-binary-columns)

I'd use something like that to get column indicies:

```
bivalued <- apply(my.data.frame, 2, is.binary)

nominal <- my.data.frame[,!bivalued]
binary <- my.data.frame[,bivalued]
```

Sample data:

```
my.data.frame <- data.frame(c(0,1), rnorm(100), c(5, 19), letters[1:5], c('a', 'b'))
> apply(my.data.frame, 2, is.binary)
     c.0..1.   rnorm.100.     c.5..19. letters.1.5.  c..a....b.. 
        TRUE        FALSE         TRUE        FALSE         TRUE
```

Comment: You could use `sapply(my.data.frame, is.binary)` instead of `apply`.

Comment: Yeah, I like the explicitness of apply.  Is sapply faster?

Comment: @Justin I would suggest to use `lapply` or `sapply`, since you are working with a data.frame, i.e. a list. `apply` does the same but has to convert the data to an array first. See my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure which is faster. `apply` only works on arrays though, so your data.frame is converted to a matrix before `is.binary` is applied. It's not an issue in this case, but can provide confusing output (e.g. compare `apply(iris,2,is.numeric)` with `sapply(iris,is.numeric)`).

Comment: Ah, now that I actually look at the apply code ... you are correct.  I'll have to mend my ways!