# How to identify all columns that contain binary representation

Tags: r

Having a dataframe like this:

```
dframe <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), Google = c(2,1,1), Yahoo = c(0,1,1), Amazon = c(1,1,0))
```

How is it possible to test every column if it contains binary (0 and 1) representation or not (max number in every row is not greater than 1)

Example

```
colname, binary_status
Google, False
Yahoo, True
Amazon, True
```

Comment: Take a look at `is.logical`. It might also depend on how you set up your data.

Comment: `apply(dframe[,2:4], 2, function(x) { max(x)<=1})`

Comment: `sapply(dframe, function(x) all(x %in% 0:1))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We could use `colSums` with `stack`

```
stack(colSums(dframe[-1] > 1) == 0)

#  values    ind
#1  FALSE Google
#2   TRUE  Yahoo
#3   TRUE Amazon
```

---

Some other methods using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dframe %>% summarise_at(-1, ~all(. < 2))
```

Or using `apply`

```
!apply(dframe[-1] > 1, 2, any)
```

Answer (score 3):

A `tidyverse` approach:

```
dframe %>% 
  purrr::map_lgl(~all(.x %in% c(0,1)))
    id Google  Yahoo Amazon 
 FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
```

Or if you want it in the exact format:

```
 dframe %>% 
   purrr::map_lgl(~all(.x %in% c(0,1))) %>% 
 .[-1] %>% 
   as.data.frame() %>%  
   setNames("values")
       values
Google  FALSE
Yahoo    TRUE
Amazon   TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own fnction:

```
is_binary <- function(x) length(unique(x)) == 2


sapply(dframe, is_binary)

 #id Google  Yahoo Amazon 
 #FALSE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
```

If you're actually looking for `0` and `1` binary, you can do:

```
is_binary <- function(x) all(unique(x) %in% c(0, 1))

sapply(dframe, is_binary)
 #  id Google  Yahoo Amazon 
 #FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
```

Comment: In the desired output, only 0,1 is accepted if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

```
apply(my.table,2,function(x) { all(na.omit(x) %in% 0:1) })
```

should work

Credits: 
Ben
[Identify binary columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830963/identify-binary-columns)

Answer (score 2):

An option is

```
dframe[!Reduce(`|`, lapply(dframe[-1], `>`, 0)),]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use grep and length for the comparison:

```
is_binary<- function(x) {length(grep(1, x))+length(grep(0, x))==nrow(dframe)}
sapply(dframe,is_binary)
#id    Google  Yahoo Amazon 
#FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
```